# Can't call Cloud Code from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I have a JavaScript client which connects to my local Parse server just fine. Login works, `Parse.Query` works, however calling any Cloud Code function with `Parse.Cloud.run` does *not* work -- instead I get the error `100/XMLHttpRequest failed`. Calling CC functions from commandline using `curl` does work, indicating that the overall server setup is correct.

It's obviously a client configuration problem on my part, but I just can't figure out what the problem might be. Client setup is simple enough:

```
Parse.initialize('myappid');
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my CC funtion requires a Date argument but I passed in a moment object... now I converted it to Date and all is well again. Silly me, but 100/XMLHttpRequest failed/ConnectionFailed is also a very misleading error message for this!